# While-Loop-Multiple-Print GC Percentage

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, break

I'm trying to write a program to get the percentage of GC's in a DNA sequence.

```
print("Enter With Z to finish")
while True:
    sequence_dna = input("Enter with sequence:")
    print("DNA Sequence:\t\t",sequence_dna)
    dna = sequence_dna
    DNA = dna.upper()
    DNAlist = list(DNA)
    CountC = sequence_dna.count("C")
    CountG = sequence_dna.count("G")
    GC = (100*(CountC+CountG)/float(len(dna)))
    print("the percentage of GC is: %.2f"%GC)
```

I also need to write a program that asks for multiple DNA strings, not just one like I did. What do I have to do?
The program need to end using the `break` command, and indicate which DNA sequence has the most GC's.

For example:

```
In DNA Sequence(0)
Out percentage of DNA Sequence(0)
enter code here
In DNA Sequence(1)
Out percentage of DNA Sequence(1)
enter code
In DNA Sequence(2)
Out percentage of DNA Sequence(2)
   break
   the DNA Sequence(1) have the highest percentage of GC`s
```

Comment: @SiHa, I tagged Bioinformatics because this is a very common question that a person doing bioinformatics work would ask.

Comment: @K.Land_bioinfo: Maybe, but it is purely a programming question. The fact that the code is being used in a bioinformatics context is irrelevant here; the question is simply how to store multiple results and return the maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
from operator import itemgetter    

print("Enter With 'z' to finish") #must be lowercase 'z'

dna_list = []

while True:
    sequence_dna = input("Enter DNA sequence: ")
    print("DNA Sequence:\t\t",sequence_dna)
    dna = sequence_dna
    DNA = dna.upper()

    dna_list.append(DNA)

    if sequence_dna == 'z':
        break

gc_percentages = []

for sequence in dna_list[:-1]: # Takes all elements of the list except for the empty entry in the last position.

    CountC = sequence.count("C")
    CountG = sequence.count("G")
    GC = str((((CountC + CountG)/len(sequence)) * 100)) + '%'
    print("The percentage of GC content for the sequence in list position %s is: %s"%(dna_list.index(sequence), GC))

    gc_percentages.append((sequence, (((CountC + CountG)/len(sequence)) * 100) ))


sorted_gc_scores = sorted(gc_percentages, key= itemgetter(1), reverse= True)

print ("\nThe sequence with the highest GC percentage of %s is:\n%s" %(str(sorted_gc_scores[0][1]) + '%', sorted_gc_scores[0][0]))
```

Once the code has run, you can reference to which sequence in dna_list gives the highest GC percentage.